# How to add binary dependencies for bundlerEnv

Tags: nix

I've been trying to add some binary dependencies to a gemset I'm passing to `bundlerEnv`. The gem itself contains a binary extension component which requires a specific native library to be present.

I can't seem to find the `bundlerEnv` definition though and the docs have only pure-ruby examples. How would I add a dependency on some `libfoobar` (available in nixpkgs) to gemset entry like:

```
  foo = {
    dependencies = [];
    gem_platform = "ruby";
    groups = ["default"];
    platforms = [];
    source = {
      remotes = ["https://rubygems.org"];
      sha256 = "...";
      type = "gem";
    };
    target_platform = "x86_64-darwin-21";
    version = "1.2.3";
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for bundlerEnv is at https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/development/ruby-modules/bundler-env/default.nix.

If you would do a PR to nixpkgs I would say to add it to https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/development/ruby-modules/gem-config/default.nix but I don't know how to do that out of tree.